# Conditional sentences using had

Tags: conditional-constructions

> **Had** you read Betty Azar carefully, you **were** able to persuade your tutor.

Is this sentence correct? or should it be:

> **Had** you read Betty Azar carefully, you **would be** able to persuade your tutor.

I mean a mixed conditional. If so , can we bring mixed conditionals with **had**?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is not grammatically correct.  If you want to use the conditional, you have to use one of the conditional tenses.

Your second sentence is fine. Here, "would" implies the condition of "being able to persuade the tutor". I don't think there is much of a difference in grammar between the structures "If A had (done) B" and "Had A (done) B":

> **If** you **had bought** the stock back then, you **would be** rich today.
>   **Had** you **bought** the stock back then, you **would be** rich today.

so if you are confused about how to start the conditional with "had" just write it starting with "if" and then convert:

> **If** you **had got** better grades, you **would be** making more money now.
>   **Had** you **got** better grades, you **would be** making more money now.

Your example is a little unclear to me because, presumably, you still have time to read Betty Azar if you want to persuade your tutor *in the future*.

> If you **read** Betty Azar carefully, you **will be able** to persuade your tutor.

If your chance has already passed, then you should change to the past tense to indicate a *missed opportunity*:

> **Had** you **read** Betty Azar carefully, you **would have been** able to persuade your tutor.